# Cannot generate a Fourier series of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to generate the fourier series of a function.  The function is constructed from a series of points:

```
points = {{395.4416644777464`, 
    207.63931734339303`}, {391.15890276860114`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {382.59337935031067`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {378.3106176411653`, 
    209.0669045797748`}, {369.74509422287485`, 
    177.65998537937617`}, {361.1795708045843`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {355.46922185905726`, 
    204.78414287062958`}, {346.9036984407667`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {341.19334949523966`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {332.6278260769492`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {326.9174771314222`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {322.6347154222768`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {316.9243664767498`, 
    219.06001523444706`}, {314.06919200398636`, 
    241.90141101655524`}, {304.076081349314`, 
    119.12890868772422`}, {295.5105579310235`, 
    327.5566451994606`}, {278.3795110944425`, 
    156.24617683364988`}, {269.8139876761519`, 
    251.8945216712275`}, {264.1036387306249`, 
    196.218619452339`}, {258.39328978509786`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {249.8277663668073`, 
    233.33588759826466`}, {241.26224294851679`, 
    173.37722367023093`}, {231.26913229384448`, 
    184.79792156128497`}, {224.13119611193568`, 
    286.1566153443896`}, {215.56567269364515`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {199.86221309344583`, 
    303.28766218097076`}, {184.1587534932465`, 
    72.01852988712619`}, {172.73805560219247`, 
    587.3775222209401`}, {162.74494494752017`, 
    83.43922777818022`}, {149.89665982008435`, 
    260.4600450895181`}, {145.61389811093912`, 
    254.74969614399106`}, {138.47596192903032`, 
    317.56353454478824`}, {131.33802574712158`, 
    183.37033432490318`}, {124.20008956521278`, 
    193.36344497957543`}, {119.91732785606749`, 
    160.52893854279512`}, {112.77939167415872`, 
    214.77725352530183`}, {108.49662996501345`, 
    199.07379392510256`}, {105.64145549224995`, 
    250.4669344348457`}, {101.35869378310466`, 
    324.70147072669704`}, {98.50351931034115`, 
    224.77036417997408`}, {91.36558312843238`, 
    220.48760247082885`}, {81.37247247376007`, 
    96.28751290561604`}, {75.66212352823305`, 
    200.50138116148423`}, {72.80694905546954`, 
    351.82562821795045`}, {54.24831498250671`, 
    154.8185895972681`}, {41.4000298550709`, 
    240.47382378017346`}, {35.68968090954388`, 
    236.19106207102823`}, {32.83450643678037`, 
    280.4462663988626`}, {12.848285127435787`, 
    131.97719381515992`}, {7.1379361819087705`, 227.62553865273765`}};
```

Which are used to give the piecewise function:

```
Clear[t];
f[t_] = Piecewise[
   Partition[Sort[points], 2, 
     1] /. {{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= t < c}];
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 400}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Then the Fourier series should result from

```
FD[t_] = FourierSeries[f[t], t, 10]
```

But no result, just "0"

However, if I try with the  given points:

```
draupnerpoints = {{-5, 0}, {-4.8, 3}, {-4.5, 1}, {-4.2, 1}, {-4, 
    3.5}, {-3.8, 0}, {-3.5, 6}, {-3.1, 0}, {-3, -5.5}, {-2.8, 
    0}, {-2.5, 6}, {-2.1, 0}, {-1.8, -2.5}, {-1.5, 0}, {-1.2, 
    5}, {-0.8, 0}, {-0.5, -8}, {-0.2, 0}, {0, 18}, {1/2, 
    0}, {2/3, -8}, {1, 0}, {4/3, 4}, {3/2, 0}, {1.6, -4}, {2, 
    3}, {2.5, -3}, {3, 3}, {3.2, -2}, {3.5, 2}, {3.8, -4}, {4.2, 
    0}, {4.5, 6}, {4.8, -5}, {5, 0.1}};
g[t_] = Piecewise[
   Table[{draupnerpoints[[i, 2]], draupnerpoints[[i, 1]] > t}, {i, 
     Length[draupnerpoints]}], 0];
p0 = Plot[g[t], {t, -5, 5}]


GD[t_] = FourierSeries[g[t], t, 10]
```

it works.

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Consider definition of the Fourier series. Your function is zero between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, so the result is also zero.

Comment: It cannot be that. Have a look at the update

Comment: Think again about @kirma's comment: your function is zero on 0 to $\pi$, and `FourierSeries` constructs a Fourier series assuming that the interval is -$\pi$ to $\pi$, and so of course the Fourier series is zero.  The second example is non-zero on this interval, which is why it doesn't give zero.

Comment: So why do I get a series outside the interval of $[-\pi,\pi]$ for the second example?

Comment: I would need to shift the coordinates along the x-axis in the [-x] direction, of 172 units. How can that be done?

Comment: ... Because a Fourier series repeats, i.e., is periodic.

Comment: You'll need to shift your function by 172 units, then use the `FourierSeries` with different `FourierParameters` (look up `FourierSeries` in the documentation for how to do this), then shift your function back.

Comment: @kirma: Yeah, I was responding to OP, not you: I was asking them to re-read and try to understand what your comment was getting at.

Comment: The function can remain at 172 unints before, but how do I do that ?

Comment: You shift a function in Mathematica the same way that you would do it *mathematically*.

Comment: That process must be automatical on all coordinates. The points are given in coordinates. I would need to subtract 172 from all the x's. But how is that done in Mathematica code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already has been said, a function to be fourier transformed must be defined between -Pi and Pi. This means you must shift and scale your function f like:

```
f1[t_] = f[(200 (t + Pi)/Pi)];
Plot[f1[t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image]

With this you may get the fourier transform:

```
FD[t_] = FourierSeries[f1[t], t, 5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

try the following:
your function:

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[Partition[Sort[points], 2, 1] /.{{a_?NumericQ, b_}, {c_, d_}} :> {b, a <= t < c}];
```

shift the function and compute the fourier series

```
{shift, shiftback} = {Rescale[t, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {0, 400}], 
   Rescale[t, {0, 400}, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}]};

fr = FourierSeries[f[t] /. t -> shift, t, 20] /. t -> shiftback // Simplify;
Plot[{f[t], fr}, {t, 0, 400}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Superb! Thanks .

Comment: @Vangsnes you are welcome